# Как сравнить 2 столбцы и соотнести данные одного к другому

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, таблицы, excel-формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]`Столбцы П1, П2, Да/Нет` являются значениями `Столбца 2`

Задача։ сравнить значения Столбец 1 и Столбец 2, найти совпадения и дальше прикрепить значения Столбец 2 к выявленным совпадениям Столбец 1.

Результат должен быть таким, как это показано в скриншоте

Answer (score 0):

Для Google Таблиц попробуйте такую формулу:

```
=filter(B1:E; ПОИСКПОЗ(B1:B; A1:A; 0))
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я забыл добавить, что Столбец 2 длиннее, чем Столбец 1. Обновил скриншот. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, меняется ли от этого условие. И можно ли сделать так, чтобы изначально добавились значения Столбец1. То есть собака и далее кошка.

Comment: @Незнайка разница в длине столбцов роли не играют.  Значения выводятся именно в таком порядке потому, что данные из диапазона B:E являются диапазоном поиска, а данные из первого столбца - объектом поиска

Comment: проблема в том, что если, например, в Столбец 2 добавить однокоренное слово "левчик", то формула считает это совпадением со словом "лев" и добавляет строку в новую таблицу. Есть решение по этой проблеме?

Comment: @Незнайка изменил функцию, теперь отображаются только точные соответствия, то есть "лев" и "левчик" и подобные не будут добавляться

Answer (score 0):

Для *Excel*.

В `G3` (копировать ячейку вниз):

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ИНДЕКС($A$3:$A$9;НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B:B;$A$3:$A$9);СТРОКА($A$3:$A$9)-2);СТРОКА(A1)));"")
```

Формула массива, ввод завершается тремя клавишами `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками.

В `H3` (копировать ячейку вниз и вправо):

```
=ЕСЛИ($G3="";"";ВПР($G3;$B$3:$E$9;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1);))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]